# Sort list of lists in R: sort one lists' value depending on other lists' value

Tags: r, list

I need some help with sorting a list of lists. Suppose I have a list of children given as following:

```
a <- list(name = "Ann", age = 9)
b <- list(name = "Bobby", age = 17)
c <- list(name = "Alex", age = 6)

my.list <- list(a, b, c)
```

I would like to sort their names by their age, so receive the following:

```
> "Alex" "Ann" "Bobby"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a <- list(name = "Ann", age = 9)
b <- list(name = "Bobby", age = 17)
c <- list(name = "Alex", age = 6)

L <- list(a,b,c)
ages <- sapply(L,"[[","age")
names <- sapply(L,"[[","name")
names[order(ages)]
```

Comment: Definitely it! Thank you, Ben.