# R: Sorting list by values in nested list

Tags: r, list, sorting

Data is generated by similar process:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- c("a", "b", "c") 
# chr vectors might have varying length and contents, simplified for sake of example
data_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  data_list <- append(data_list, list(list(numeric = x[i], char = y)))
}
```

Basically, structure of generated list looks like:

```
$ :List of 2
  ..$ numeric: num 0.928
  ..$ char   : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ numeric: num 1.4
  ..$ char   : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
...
```

I would like to sort this list by numeric in ascending order, retaining initial structure.

I have tried solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217309/sort-list-of-lists-in-r-sort-one-lists-value-depending-on-other-lists-value) but it disrupts the structure of chr vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data_list = data_list[order(sapply(data_list, `[[`, i=1))]
```

Comment: And this solution works for both example and actual data, which makes me wonder - what exactly went wrong with agstudy solution.

Comment: While we're at it - could you please suggest any good materials about apply functions? I have always seen them having a great potential but never quite got hang of them.

Comment: @A.Val. Personnaly I would use `sapply` for this solution(+1). `rappaly` is to use when you have a nested list with longer depth.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
data_list[order(rapply(data_list,"numeric",f=c))]
```

`rapply` intsruction will extract all numeric values, then we `order` them.

Comment: For some reason this solution works for provided example but gives a weird error when I apply it to actual data. I will look into it as to what might have caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
data_list[order(unlist(do.call(`c`, data_list)[c(T,F)]))]
```